Generate a shellscript menu with hosts addresses from a file and display the options with a "ping status" below each option?
Question: Generate a shellscript menu with hosts addresses from a file and display the options with a "ping status" below each option? Do you have some idea to help?
Filename: bssh.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Display Servers
echo "Servers List"
echo ""
SERVERS="servers_list.txt"
while IFS= read -r SERVERS_LINE || [[ -n "$SERVERS_LINE" ]]; do
    serveraddress=$(echo $SERVERS_LINE | cut -d"@" -f 2)
    servername=$(echo $SERVERS_LINE | cut -d"@" -f 1)
    if ping -c 1 -W 1 $serveraddress >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo -e "$servername [\033[0;32mOnline\033[0m]"
        echo ""
    else
        echo -e "$servername [\033[0;31mOffline\033[0m]"
        echo ""
    fi
done <"$SERVERS"
readarray -t Servers < servers_list.txt
PS3=$'\n'"Enter your choice or 0 to exit: "
select selection in "${Servers[@]}"; do
    if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "\033[0;90mPeace Out!\033[0m" >&2
        exit
    else
        # Modify the way the program is called
        if [[ -e /usr/bin/ssh ]]; then
            echo ""
            ssh "$selection"
            #echo ""
        else
            echo ""
            ssh "$selection"
            #echo ""
        fi
        break
    fi
done

Filename: servers_list.txt
root@127.0.0.1  
validusername@127.0.0.1  
ufo@nasa.vog
   

